# Is there a way to rethrow Selenium error message?

Tags: python, selenium

If i wrap a piece of Selenium Webdriver code by "try except" in Python, with self.fail('some problem') in the except block, i don't get to know what Selenium would have said at that point. If there had been no try-except, Selenium gives an error message, e.g about visibility, or staleness of element, etc. How can a Webdriver program re-throw the Selenium error report ?

Comment: Are you talking about [`raise` with no arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-raise_stmt)?

Comment: I didn't know of this method in Python. I shall try it.

Answer (score 2):

Several options:

```
try:
  ...
except SeleniumException as problem:
  raise
```

or

```
try:
  ...
except SeleniumException as problem:
  raise problem
```

both will re-throw the original exception.  The first will keep the original stack (so you can see into Selenium itself), the latter will handle the exception as if it occurred not inside Selenium but at the point of the `raise`.

But typically you have new information at that point, so you might want to add that while keeping the original stack trace and exception information.  For this, sometimes *changing* the caught exception before rethrowing it is proposed; that's something I don't propose because it isn't a very general approach.  I'd rather stick to the following:  Python 3 knows *exception chaining*:

```
try:
  ...
except SeleniumException as problem:
  raise MyNewException("some additional information") from problem
```

And in case you need even more features or maybe you are on Python 2, you can have a look at my [`CausedException`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578252-python-exception-chains-or-trees/) class.  It can be used also if you need to give more than one cause (old exceptions) for the new exception.